# Hide parent element on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Learning Angular JS, trying a simple function where clicking an element hides its parent element.

My code:

```
<div class="form-section" ng-init="visible = true" ng-show="visible">   
     <a class="next" ng-click="$parent.visible = false">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

However, nothing happens when I click my `<a>` tag.

I based my code on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxda3aes/

Comment: The bit of code you posted looks fine. Maybe something's wrong with how you're including Angular, or initializing the app.

Comment: My browser isn't throwing me any errors, so I'm not sure how I would check if I'm including Angular correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `$parent`

What you're doing is creating a variable on the scope called `visible` and setting it to true.
So all you need to do to change the variable is call `visible`
[`$parent` isn't referencing a parent node, it's referencing a parent scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

```
<div class="form-section" ng-init="visible = true" ng-show="visible">   
    <a class="next" ng-click="visible = false">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oxda3aes/25/

This might help you see a little better what's happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/oxda3aes/26/

Here I declare the visible variable in the controller. Both accomplish the same task.

And here I have a function on the scope that gets called on click that does the same thing:
http://jsfiddle.net/oxda3aes/27/

Answer (score 0):

$parent in angular does not mean parent element in HTML structure, but nested scopes relation. In mentioned by you example, ng-repeat creates child scopes for each it's iteration, and $parent in this case from this child scope points to its parent scope. In your case both HTML elements belong to the same scope, so, as was already answered just do not use $parent in your case.

When dealing with parent child scopes interactions in angular, it is always to use objects for your ng-models, rather then primitives (*ngModel="obj.property"* instead of just *ngModel="property"*), see very good article about scopes in angular https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: How would you recommend doing this so that the parent element specifically is what's hidden? I have other '<form-section>'s, so I want to make sure only the parent of '<a class="next"> is what's hidden.

Comment: the only angular approach that I can think of is to use different scope variables, and also you do not need ng-init for each form section if you will use negations, see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2WrpqgRMTeefziyheYUi?p=preview. I added in this example also pure JS approach - binding click event to all NEXT a tags, and adding to their parents 'ng-hide' class